# As for you, Frodo, in so far as lies in me

Tags: syntactic-analysis, literature, archaicisms, conjugation

It's from *The Lord of the Rings*:

> ‘Then I will declare my doom,’ said Faramir. ‘As for you, Frodo, in so
>   far as lies in me under higher authority, I declare you free in the
>   realm of Gondor to the furthest of its ancient bounds; save only that
>   neither you nor any that go with you have leave to come to this place
>   unbidden. This doom shall stand for a year and a day, and then cease,
>   unless you shall before that term come to Minas Tirith and present
>   yourself to the Lord and Steward of the City.

1. I can't understand the conjugation of the verb "lies" in the second sentence. 
   Since it seems that the subject of the sentence is "you", instead of "Frodo"
   Which one is the correct subject of this sentence?

   [As for "you", in so far as "lies" in me under my authority, ~~]
2. I couldn't find the particular sense of the word "doom" as it is used in the context of this novel provided in any modern dictionary. Does it just mean the new rule (regulation) applied to the individual temporarily?
3. So the rule of Faramir is that Frodo is "free" to come to this place (Gondor) only when he is allowed (have leave / unbidden)?

Comment: "in so far as lies in me under higher authority" is a parenthetical.

Comment: I interpret "in so far as lies in me under higher authority" to mean *to the extent that it falls within my power under higher authority* - the "it" in "it lies" has been elided. A *doom* is a law or ordinance - see [the first definition in MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doom), a dictionary I regard as definitely "modern". You might like to add it to your dictionary searches in future :-)

Comment: @Chappo I think in this case it's a judgement that he is speaking now under his delegated authority from Denethor. It's like a judge pronouncing a sentence, making a ruling.

Comment: @tchrist yes, that makes more sense. And it’s sense #2 in MW. It’s always nice to find new depth in words you thought you were familiar with: I’d only ever been aware of the 3rd sense of *doom*, i.e. fate or ruin.